# Yii2 Filtering Gridview within Modal Dialog?

Tags: modal-dialog, yii2, pjax

i've been trying to create **yii\jui\Dialog** that is triggered on button click in the form view. the Dialog itself will contain a *Gridview* Widget within it using **Yii 2.0**.

i have managed to create the dialog and fill it with the *Gridview* widget. the only problem that i encounter is that the *Gridview* within the dialog is can't be filtered properly. the filter process is fine though, but every time i filtered the *Gridview*, the Dialog modal will also be closed.

i also have tried to use Pjax by encapsulate the gridview within Pjax widget. this time the modal Dialog won't be closed. but then it can only filter 1 time. once the *Gridview* is filtered then we can't filter it anymore.

below is my "_form" view : (i am using button called "cari" to trigger the pop up dialog)

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'judul')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'isi')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'kategori_id', [
    'addon' =>  ['append' => 
                    ['content'=> 
                        Html::button('x', ['class'=>'btn btn-default','name' => 'del_kat', 'id' => 'del_kat', 'onclick' => '$("#kat_id").val("");'])  . PHP_EOL .
                        Html::button('Cari', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary','id' => 'modal_kat', 'onclick' => '$("#kategori_dialog").dialog("open"); return false;' ]),

                        'asButton' => true
                    ]
                ]
])->textInput(['id'=> 'kat_id', 'readonly' => true]) ?>
```

here is my *GridView* Code :

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $kategoriModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams),
    'filterModel' => $kategoriModel,
    'columns' => [
        'kategori_id',
        'nama',
         [
            'label' => 'test',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($data) {

                return Html::button('+', ['class'=>'btn btn-default','id' => 'modal_kat', 'onclick' => '$("#kategori_dialog").dialog("close"); $("#kat_id").val("'.$data->kategori_id.'");' ]);
            },
        ],


    ],

]);
```

and here is Dialog Code :

```
Dialog::begin([
'id' => 'kategori_dialog',
'clientOptions' => [
    'modal' => true,
    'autoOpen'=>false,
     'title'=>'List Kategori',
     'width'=>'auto',
],

]);

Pjax::begin(['id' => 'kategori-pjax', 'enablePushState'=>false]);
echo $kategoriGrid;
Pjax::end(); 

Dialog::end();
```

as you guys can see, i tried to use Pjax but i couldn't make it work as expected (as i can only filter the *Gridview* once then it can be filtered again). i remember doing this just fine back in Yii 1.1 (i was using CJuiDialog back).

so i wonder if i am missing something here in **Yii 2.0**? i am kinda new to Pjax stuff, so i think i miss some properties that have to be set in the Pjax widget.

Comment: Can you edit and display all View content?

Comment: yup, it shouldn't be a problem at all. all functionality is fine. the only problem for me is to make the gridview inside the Modal dialog can be filtered. i think it has something to do with Pjax container that should be refreshed / reloaded, but i am still investigating it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the solution to this is by using Kartik's Gridview. i installed it and set the Pjax property to true.

```
use kartik\grid\GridView; 
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $model,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'pjax' =>true,
]);
```

and now i can successfully filter the grid within the dialog. it looks like Kartik has better implementation when wrapping the Grid with Pjax Container.